# Do you need to reload after adding a rule in ufw?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ufw

Do you need to run any of these commands:

```
sudo ufw reload
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw enable
```

after adding a rule via `sudo ufw allow`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No. It's enough to just add it. But if you add rules in the files, you need to execute `commit`.

You can check user rules, as they're called with:

```
ufw status
```

You can also add `verbose` for some details:

```
ufw status verbose
```

Or `numbered` to know which rule to remove with `delete`. The syntax for this one is this:

```
ufw delete <RULE NUMBER>
```

Comment: 1 more question please. What do you mean by "add rules in the files"?

Comment: @iLW Take a look in `/etc/ufw/`. There are many rules there. What you add through the command line goes to `user` or `user6` for IPv6. There should be 6 more folders there and a cover of `sysctl.conf` form `/etc/sysctl` and `/etc/sysctl.d`. Find a suitable guide for your OS and version. There are plenty of them in the air.

Comment: sudo ufw commit results in Error: Invalid syntax

Comment: @MarissaLevy This shouldn't happen. Start a new question with your details.

Comment: delete RULE needs reload? It seems like it is the case for me.. is it normal?

Comment: you need to execute commit makes it sound like there's a command ufw commit
Should be (?) ufw reload

Comment: actually there's also ufw app update PROFILE

Comment: There is no `commit` on ubuntu.