# UFW does not block any ports (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: ubuntu

On my fresh Hetzner Cloud server, the ufw seems to be ineffective. The status output is the following:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Despite ufw being active on this fresh install, all ports are accessible (I removed the IP from the screenshot):

[image]

Is a reboot required after activating ufw or an ufw rule?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370942/do-you-need-to-reload-after-adding-a-rule-in-ufw

Comment: You are going to need to explain a lot more about the network set up and how you are connecting to those ports. Also if that external connection is actually hitting the server or an intermediary. As for the question you actually asked, it's googleable.